# How to correctly initialize a constant vector with a value from a list in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting myself familiar with OOP, so please forgive my ignorance. My question is about how to correctly initialize a constant vector using a vector value from a list in C#. I tired this but was not acceptable:

```
const Vector<double> Val= myList.ElementAt<Vector<double>>(0);
```

I want the Val to be constant in a loop. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a complete example of what you want to do? What are you trying to gain from `const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# `const` implies that the value is known at compile time. If this was a member of a class you could use `readonly` to prevent it from changing after the constructor is finished. However, from your question, this is not a member of a class. There is currently no way to get the compiler to prevent a reassignment for a local variable.

Also, I am guessing you don't want to use `ElementAt` in this case.

Even if you used `ElementAt` you can drop the generic part `<Vector<double>>` in this case as it can be infered.

If you have a list as you say, you can use `myList[0]`.
Otherwise you can use the Linq method `First`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `const` to [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx), since you can't instantiate a `const`outside the class definition.

From MSDN:

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, **assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class**.

That means you have to set this variable in the constructor, just like you have to do with your `myList` variable. If that is not what you want, drop the `const` since it isn't a constant value anyways then.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! And thank you Patrick. I later created an extra function to handle that.